# box2d: GetLinearVelocity() to detect motion?

Tags: box2d

Pretty simple question: will the result of `b2Body::GetLinearVelocity` tell me if an object is in motion? I would expect that it would - does it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`GetLinearVelocity()` returns a `b2Vec2`. You could use `b2Vec2::Length()` to find the magnitude of the velocity; if it is zero, the object is not moving.

Answer (score 2):

It would tell you if the body is moving. However it could also happen to be spinning in one place around the origin and `getLinearVelocity()` would return zero. So if you want to be definitely sure that no motion is happening you should check `getAngularVelocity()` as well.